# How to create multiple dataframes, from a large dataframe grouping by division and subdivision, in a loop,

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
data_group = data.groupby(['division','subdivision'])

for i  in range(1 , 4):

  for j  in range(1 , 4):
  
  #output ex:
  
   divisao__%i%__subdivisao__%j% = dados_agrupados .get_group((i, j))
```

There would be 16 new data frames with the name: division_1_sub_1, division_1_sub_2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the groups, convert each group to a dataframe, and store the 16 resulting dataframes in a dictionary.  The dictionary key for each dataframe is a string constructed on the basis of division and subdivision values.

```
#construct original dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

#group by division and subdivision:
groups = df.groupby(['division', 'subdivision'])

#create dictionary to store new dataframes
dataframes = {}

#iterate through the groups and create a new dataframe from each group
for _,group in groups:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(group)
    #add the new dataframe to dataframes dictionary. Set its key (name) according to the division and subdivision
    dataframes[f'df_division{int(new_df.division.mode())}_subdivision{int(new_df.subdivision.mode())}'] = new_df

print(len(dataframes)) #16

#You can access each of the 16 dataframes like the below example:
print(dataframes['df_division1_subdivision2'])
```